# Why does the parent process explicitly recycle the resource of child process by using waitpid?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Why does the parent process have to explicitly recycle the resource of child process by using waitpid?
I can not understand why linux designs in this way.
I think it will be much simpler if the resource is recycled by kernel when the child process exit.

Comment: "I think it will be much simpler if the resource is recycled by kernel when the child process exit." - At some point, the parent process would want to know about the child state. What should the parent do, if the child is completely destroyed?

Comment: I don't think parent process should have to  explicitly recycle the resource of child process. `waitpid` just a kind of synchronization or communication between parent and child.